# SVN to GIT migration using Tortoise Git

Tags: git, svn, tortoisegit

I'm trying to push the code to GIT from SVN. I have used Tortoise Git tool to pull out the code with specific revision numbers (this folder contains `.git` folder and a svn folder inside `.git` folder) successfully.

I'm now trying to push the code/folder to GIT. Please let me know if I need to delete svn folder (which is inside `.git` folder) or any other configurations before pushing. Also please let me know if there will be any challenges in this approach.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to permanently move your project from SVN to Git? If so, the Pro Git Book has a chapter on [Migrating To Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git).

Answer (score 2):

Try using a tool like [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) instead. It should automate the entire process. I used it to migrate from SVN to Git (not because I don't like SVN, but because our company mandated it) but it can handle migrations in the other direction too, as well as bidirectional syncing.